# Concept behind MediaBrowserServiceCompat.onLoadChildren()

Tags: android, mobile, android-mediaplayer, mediabrowserservicecompat

I am attempting to create a simple audio app and am referencing Google's [MediaBrowserService](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-MediaBrowserService/) example. My question is really grasping the concept behind *MediaBrowserServiceCompat.onLoadChildren()* and *MediaSessionCompat.Callback* methods *onAddQueueItem* and *onRemoveQueueItem*

```
@Override
public void onLoadChildren(@NonNull final String parentMediaId,
        @NonNull final Result<List<MediaBrowserCompat.MediaItem>> result) {

    Log.d(TAG, "onLoadChildren(): ------------------->");

    result.sendResult(MusicLibrary.getMediaItems());
}
```

---

```
@Override
public void onAddQueueItem(MediaDescriptionCompat description) {
    mPlaylist.add(new MediaSessionCompat.QueueItem(description, description.hashCode()));
    mQueueIndex = (mQueueIndex == -1) ? 0 : mQueueIndex;
    mSession.setQueue(mPlaylist);
}

@Override
public void onRemoveQueueItem(MediaDescriptionCompat description) {
    mPlaylist.remove(new MediaSessionCompat.QueueItem(description, description.hashCode()));
    mQueueIndex = (mPlaylist.isEmpty()) ? -1 : mQueueIndex;
    mSession.setQueue(mPlaylist);
}
```

Mass confusion sets when I try to reconcile **onAddQueueItem** and **onRemoveQueueItem** methods with **onLoadChildren**. Does the onAddQueueItem() automatically generate *MediaBrowserCompat.MediaItems* that were sent/made available via the *result.sendResult()* in **onLoadChildren()** method? or am I confusing myself even further by trying to link the two ? if anyone has blogs/articles/youtube videos that will help broaden my understanding, it be much obliged.